# Status-bar / SafeArea issue with Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I was using SafeAreaView for my screens and it behaved normally:

- Safe areas' background color is the same as the rest of my screen
- The content is simply padded within the safe area insets, just like it is supposed to be.

Then I added expo-router for my navigation:

- At first, it was fine
- But then when I started playing with headers -> 'headerShown: true/false', and now ever since:

  - SafeAreaView started adding additional layer of insets (double padding) on top of the safe areas

    [safeareaview with additional (double) padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XbNv.png)
- Then I removed SafeAreaView and now it is automatically within the safe area insets

  - I am assuming safe areas are integrated in expo-router
- BUT, I cannot customize the safe areas now

  - they are always white and I cannot get rid of them or change the color of the background to merge well with my content (rest of my screen)
  - I am using expo-status-bar but it does help to style it anyhow, just toggle if status bar info is hidden or not
  - [safeareaview removed, status bar persists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6fh9.png)

The problem is both on IOS and Android. I want to underline this fact, it is both on IOS and Android.

PLEASE HELP, been struggling for a while now

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue here. I solved it by setting the header as null in the screenOptions of my root layout file (_layout) instead of setting headerShown as false.

Before, it was like this: `<Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} />` and had double padding. Now, it is like this: `<Stack screenOptions={{ header: () => null }} />` and the additional padding is gone.

My root layout file

```
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

export default function RootLayout() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <Stack screenOptions={{ header: () => null }} />
        </SafeAreaView>

    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    }
})
```

My root index file

```
import { Redirect } from 'expo-router';

export default function Page() {
    return <Redirect href={"/(drawer)/home"} />;
}
```